# jQuery Load Function inside Zend Partials

Tags: zend-framework, jquery, zend-db

How would I use the load function and append data from a partial view using jQuery and the Zend Framework? Essentially, when I click "Show More", the data from my view partial (the word hey) gets appended to the container. End result = List, (click 'show more') hey etc.

VIEW

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function(){
    $('<div id="info" />').load('/partials/view #hey', function () {
      $(this).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown(100);
    });
  })});
</script>
<div id="container">
  List
</div>
<a href="#">Show More</a>
```

VIEW PARTIAL ('/partials/view')

```
<div id="hey">
  <ul>
    <li>hey</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense: php works on a server, js on a client

Comment: I'm simply trying to take data from the view partial and display it inside the container id. So when I click "Show More", the hey id from the view partial gets appended to the container id.

Comment: you might have to make a view that contains only that partial, since partials aren't usually accessible from the browser...

Answer (score 1):

For this you will need to create an action, you cannot access the partial directly.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function(){
    $('<div id="info" />').load('controller/some-action', function () {
      $(this).hide().appendTo('#container').slideDown(100);
    });
  })});
</script>
```

> Action someAction:

```
// do your thing if required
$this->view->variable = $data;
```

Send the request to action, make sure your view has `no layout`. use your partial in the view.

In the view (some-action.phtml):

```
echo $this->partial(
  $partialName, 
  array (
    'variable' => $variable
  )
);
```

this way you will be able to utilize your partial.